# 'Constant' vector field on a Lie group is smooth

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I have  a really basic question which I am struggling to articulate formally in differential geometry. I have a Lie group $G$, and a tangent vector $v\in T_{1_G}(G)$. I want to claim that the vector field $g\mapsto(g,v)$ is a smooth vector field, but I am unsure as to whether I can say formally that $v\in T_g(G)$ for all $g\in G$.

With $G$ being a topological group, it is homogeneous, and given a chart $(U,\varphi)$ of the identity, $(gU, g^{-1} \cdot \varphi)$ is a chart around any $g$. But I'm still unsure as whether that means that $v\in T_g(G)$.

If it is trivially true that $v\in T_g(G)$ for $g$ in the same component as $1_G$, or if it true even without the topological group sturcture, I would be very thankful if someone were to help my overcome this conceptual hurdle.

Comment: What do you mean by $(g, v)$? Is it a translation?

Comment: Elements of the tangent bundles are $(g,w)$ where $g\in G$ and $w\in T_g(G)$, or am I wrong?

Comment: This does not make sense in general, and this is a fundamental fact of differential geometry. Precisely, you cannot translate vectors like that; this is why the standard notation is $w_g$ instead of $(g, w)$. Imagine a vector tangent to a circle. Move that vector elsewhere on the circle; it is not tangent anymore. **In general, translation is a subtle matter**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you're looking for here is *left-invariant vector field*. For Lie group $G$ and any $v \in T_1 G$, we can define an (a priori, rough) vector field $$\tilde v \in \Gamma(TG), \qquad \tilde v_g := T_1 L_g \cdot v .$$ Here, $L_g : G \to G$ is the left multiplication map $h \mapsto gh$. Then, unwinding definitions shows that $\tilde v$ is invariant under left multiplication, that is that
$$T_1 L_g \cdot \tilde v_h = \tilde v_{gh}$$
for all $g, h \in G$.

Conversely, there is canonical map $$\omega : TG \to T_1 G , \qquad \omega : w_g \mapsto T L_{g^{-1}} \cdot w_g ,$$ and unwinding definitions gives that $$\omega(\tilde v_g) = v.$$ If we identify $T_1 G$ with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$, $\omega$ is precisely the *Maurer-Cartan form* on $G$. This in turn defines a canonical bundle isomorphism $$\Phi : TG \to G \times T_1 G, \qquad \Phi : w_g \mapsto (g, \omega(w_g)) .$$ This bundle isomorphism formalizes the notion in the original question: Unwinding definitions shows that $\Phi^{-1}$ identifies $(g, v) \in G \times T_1 G$ with $\tilde v_g \in T_g G$.

With this in hand, we can check smoothness directly by verifying that $\tilde v \cdot f$ is smooth whenever $f$ is, and this again amounts to [unwinding definitions and recognizing that an expression for $\tilde v \cdot f$ is manifestly smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275222/a-detail-in-the-proof-that-left-invariant-vector-fields-are-smooth).

Comment: I am actually trying to show that there exists a unique left invariant field.  I am trying to define a 'simple' left invariant vector field, and later showing that it is unique.

Comment: The left-invariant vector field $\tilde v$ is unique more or less by definition: In order for $\tilde v$ to be left-invariant, then specializing the equation $T_1 L_g \cdot \tilde v_h = \tilde v_{gh}$ to $h = e$ gives $\tilde v_g = T_1 L_g \cdot v$.

Comment: Just to be sure, when working with a definition not by derivations, what exactly does $L_g\cdot v$ means?

Comment: The notation I used is, e.g., $T_1 L_g \cdot v$. Here, $T_1 L_g : T_1 G \to T_g G$ is the pushforward of the smooth map $L_g$ at $1 \in G$.

Comment: So is it the differential of $L_g$ at $1_G$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the terms are synonymous. You might also see it written as $dL_g$ or $(L_g)_*$, but I prefer the notation $T_1 L_g$ because it indicates the base point and is "functorial": The map $L_g : G \to G$ induces a map $T_1 L_g : T_1 G \to T_g G$.