# Left-invariant vector field is differentiable

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am quite new to the subject, please comment if something does not make sense.

Let $M$ be a Lie group. $L_x$ be left multiplication by $x\in M$.
 
I want to show that vector space $X:M \to TM$ defined as $X_x = T_1 L_x(v)$ is differentiable. ($v\in T_1M$)

If I am not mistaken, I need to argue the map
\begin{equation}
a \mapsto \left(a,\ T_{\varphi^{-1}(a)}\varphi (T_1L_{\varphi^{-1}(a)}(v))\right) = \left(a,\ T_1(\varphi\ \circ L_{\varphi^{-1}(a)})(v)\right) 
\end{equation}
is differentiable ($a\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\varphi$ is a chart). I am not sure how to argue tangent map is differentiable.

Comment: Surely you mean "left-invariant vector *field*".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Constant' vector field on a Lie group is smooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032588/constant-vector-field-on-a-lie-group-is-smooth)

Comment: Thanks, @Travis. [(also related)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275222/a-detail-in-the-proof-that-left-invariant-vector-fields-are-smooth)